# How to use QFT operation in Q#?

Tags: programming, q#, quantum-fourier-transform

I see the [QFT operation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.canon.qft) in the document given by Microsoft, but I don't know how to call it.

```
operation QFT (qs : Microsoft.Quantum.Arithmetic.BigEndian) : Unit is Adj + Ctl
```

Does this method need to be rewritten? How to set the parameters here? Can I have a brief example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BigEndian](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.arithmetic.bigendian) is a data type that is effectively just a wrapper for an array of qubits. If you want to apply QFT to a qubit array `register`, you need to convert it to `BigEndian` first:

```
QFT(BigEndian(register));
```

Comment: Thank you! May I ask you another question?I want to realize a quantum gate defined by myself:  [ [1, 0], [0, e^iθ ]]  . What way can I implement in Q? On the IBM Q platform, I can realize it with the specified angle value: p (θ)  q [0].

Comment: @Damon https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.intrinsic.r1

Comment: Thank you very much for your patient guidance! Here R1 needs to use radian value as a parameter, which is different from the angle value parameter.

Comment: You can convert one to another using https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.math.pi

Comment: Is the inverse Fourier transform realized by BigEndian and LittleEndian transformations?I didn't find any other way out of the way Microsoft gave me.Can you solve it?

Comment: Inverse transformations can be implemented using Adjoint functor https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/user-guide/language/expressions/functorapplication#adjoint-functor